# Generate context menu in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, contextmenu

This question was discussed widely, but I didn't find any solution yet.

I'm generating (in MyObject.Theme.xaml) an item according to data template. It has to be a button with a title. When I click on this button, it has to show see the menu generated according a collection.

But all I see is an empty context menu. It looks like it doesn't see Button's DataContext and I can't find, how to pass it to ContextMenu.

The code is following:

```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type fields:ButtonWithMenu}">
       <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Path=ButtonTitle}">
           <!--- Show ContextMenu on left mouse clik)
           <Button.Style>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                   <Style.Triggers>
                       <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                          <EventTrigger.Actions>
                              <BeginStoryboard>
                                 <Storyboard>
                                     <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                                         <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                                     </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                 </Storyboard>
                              </BeginStoryboard>
                          </EventTrigger.Actions>
                      </EventTrigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
            </Button.Style>
            <!--- Try to load items from Button.DataContext.Commands -->
            <Button.ContextMenu>
               <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Commands}">
                  <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=Title}" Command="{Binding Path=Command}" />
                     </DataTemplate>
                   </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                </ContextMenu>
             </Button.ContextMenu>
          </Button>
     </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: What is the DataType of `Commands`? Does it have the two properties, `Title` and `Command`, mentioned in the DataTemplate?

Comment: Also, where do you set the DataContext?

Comment: Commands are of my own type, that has both this fields. DataContext is set during the applying theme and it is used for button (I can see ButtonTitle loaded in it)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the DataContext…

```
<Button>
    <Button.ContextMenu >
        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Commands}">
            <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=Title}" Command="{Binding Path=Command}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Comment: Yes, I thinkj it would help, but how to attach this {Binding} to the Button's DataContext? I've tried a several variants, but they didn't help

Comment: not sure to get what you mean…  You don't know how binding works? or you cannot attach it to your userControl/Window?  or simply to the button?  `<Button DataContext="{Binding Path=MyModel}">`